# ERR_REQUIRE_ESM error in Docker-compose setup for Nuxt.js frontend

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nuxt.js

So I have a frontend with Nuxt.js and a FastAPI both in a docker container. Both server run commands work without docker.

The filesystem looks like this for docker:

```
├── Dockerfile -- FastAPI docker file
├── docker-compose.yml 
└── front
    ├── Dockerfile -- Nuxt docker file
```

When running `docker-compose up` the FastAPI server works but the nuxt throws this error

```
Nuxt-frontend  | > @ start /front
Nuxt-frontend  | > nuxt start
Nuxt-frontend  |
Nuxt-frontend  | internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:975
Nuxt-frontend  |     throw new ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename);
Nuxt-frontend  |     ^
Nuxt-frontend  |
Nuxt-frontend  | Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /front/node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.mjs
Nuxt-frontend  |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:975:11)
Nuxt-frontend  |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
Nuxt-frontend  |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
Nuxt-frontend  |     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
Nuxt-frontend  |   code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
Nuxt-frontend  | }
Nuxt-frontend  | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
Nuxt-frontend  | npm ERR! errno 1
Nuxt-frontend  | npm ERR! @ start: `nuxt start`
Nuxt-frontend  | npm ERR! Exit status 1
Nuxt-frontend  | npm ERR!
Nuxt-frontend  | npm ERR! Failed at the @ start script.
Nuxt-frontend  | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
Nuxt-frontend  |
Nuxt-frontend  | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
Nuxt-frontend  | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2023-01-07T06_09_00_616Z-debug.log
```

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:12.16.3-alpine3.9

# Create destination
RUN mkdir -p /front
WORKDIR /front


#compile app
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .
RUN npm build

EXPOSE 3000

ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV NUXT_PORT=3000

CMD [ "npm","run", "start" ]
```

the .dockerignore looks like this:

```
node_modules
npm-debug*
.nuxt
dist
tests
.output
```

The `docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
    app:
        build: .
        container_name: FastAPI
        command: uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
    front:
        build: ./front
        container_name: Nuxt-frontend
        command: npm start
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
```

Note: I already tried adding `"type": "module"` to package.json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know the cause but here is how I solved it.

Go into Docker Desktop and erase all the containers and images.

Change the docker file to this:

```
FROM node:17-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /front
WORKDIR /front
COPY . .

RUN npm ci
RUN npm cache clean --force
RUN npm run build

ENV NUXT_HOST=0.0.0.0
ENV NUXT_PORT=3000

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "node", "/front/server/index.mjs"]
```

The docker-compose.yaml looks like this:

```
front:
    build: ./front
    container_name: Nuxt-frontend
    volumes:
        - /front/node_modules
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
        - 3000:3000
```

And then run `docker compose up`